# Is there an open-source implementation of Google's Task Queue?

Tags: google-app-engine, open-source, task-queue

As the title says, I'm wondering if there's an open-source, drop-in replacement for Google's Task Queue.  The closest I've been able to find so far is [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), but that's not really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[AppScale](http://community.appscale.com/) includes a TaskQueue component, but whether it is drop-in will depend where you drop it.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly TaskQueue, but [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/features.html) and [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) could be decent drop-in replacements.